# Can't access admin screen, (white screen)

Tags: php, magento

After upgrading Magento version from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.6 via Magento Connect Manager, I can't access admin page anymore. I have tried several things I found here like:

Setting memory limit to 512M,

Clearing cache and sessions folders,

Trying to get some error output with:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

but no joy, still I'm getting just white screen without any info on it.

My admin page was not on a default path like domain.com/admin I had hidden path like domain.com/XsaWSd

==========================

I've found what's causing the white screen

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => include_once(): Failed opening '/home/ecogarden/www/www/includes/src/__adminhtml.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/ecogarden/www/www/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php56/lib/php')
    [file] => /home/ecogarden/www/www/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php
    [line] => 108
)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you see your error logs?

Comment: Yes, I can. var/log path right?

Comment: You also need to check your Apache/NGINX error log